# Can I rotate the logo circle without rotating the text in svg file?

Tags: xml, svg, rotation

This is my first time here so I hope you'll help me! 
So : I decided to make my logo (circle) to rotate, the problem is : I know how to rotate it when it's alone with `animateTransform (type : rotate)`, but when I add text, things get complicated : I only want the logo to rotate not the text. Please check the code below for rotating logo (I didn't optimize the code) :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="44.96632"
   height="44.966309"
   viewBox="0 0 44.96632 44.966309"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg1571"
   sodipodi:docname="spriologo1 - Copie.svg"
   inkscape:version="0.92.4 (5da689c313, 2019-01-14)">
  <metadata
     id="metadata1575">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <sodipodi:namedview
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1"
     objecttolerance="10"
     gridtolerance="10"
     guidetolerance="10"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:window-width="1366"
     inkscape:window-height="705"
     id="namedview1573"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:zoom="2.36"
     inkscape:cx="-32.082413"
     inkscape:cy="27.382954"
     inkscape:window-x="-8"
     inkscape:window-y="-8"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1"
     inkscape:current-layer="svg1571"
     fit-margin-top="0"
     fit-margin-left="0"
     fit-margin-right="0"
     fit-margin-bottom="0" />
  <defs
     id="defs1553">
    <marker
       inkscape:stockid="DotS"
       orient="auto"
       refY="0"
       refX="0"
       id="marker1763"
       style="overflow:visible"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         id="path1761"
         d="m -2.5,-1 c 0,2.76 -2.24,5 -5,5 -2.76,0 -5,-2.24 -5,-5 0,-2.76 2.24,-5 5,-5 2.76,0 5,2.24 5,5 z"
         style="fill:#1b4d82;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#1b4d82;stroke-width:1.00000003pt;stroke-opacity:1"
         transform="matrix(0.2,0,0,0.2,1.48,0.2)"
         inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       inkscape:stockid="DotS"
       orient="auto"
       refY="0"
       refX="0"
       id="marker1759"
       style="overflow:visible"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         id="path1757"
         d="m -2.5,-1 c 0,2.76 -2.24,5 -5,5 -2.76,0 -5,-2.24 -5,-5 0,-2.76 2.24,-5 5,-5 2.76,0 5,2.24 5,5 z"
         style="fill:#a92121;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#a92121;stroke-width:1.00000003pt;stroke-opacity:1"
         transform="matrix(0.2,0,0,0.2,1.48,0.2)"
         inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       inkscape:stockid="DotS"
       orient="auto"
       refY="0"
       refX="0"
       id="marker1755"
       style="overflow:visible"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         id="path1753"
         d="m -2.5,-1 c 0,2.76 -2.24,5 -5,5 -2.76,0 -5,-2.24 -5,-5 0,-2.76 2.24,-5 5,-5 2.76,0 5,2.24 5,5 z"
         style="fill:#1b4d82;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#1b4d82;stroke-width:1.00000003pt;stroke-opacity:1"
         transform="matrix(0.2,0,0,0.2,1.48,0.2)"
         inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       inkscape:stockid="DotS"
       orient="auto"
       refY="0"
       refX="0"
       id="DotS"
       style="overflow:visible"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         id="path1553"
         d="m -2.5,-1 c 0,2.76 -2.24,5 -5,5 -2.76,0 -5,-2.24 -5,-5 0,-2.76 2.24,-5 5,-5 2.76,0 5,2.24 5,5 z"
         style="fill:#aa2224;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#aa2224;stroke-width:1.00000003pt;stroke-opacity:1"
         transform="matrix(0.2,0,0,0.2,1.48,0.2)"
         inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       inkscape:stockid="DotM"
       orient="auto"
       refY="0"
       refX="0"
       id="DotM"
       style="overflow:visible"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         id="path1748"
         d="m -2.5,-1 c 0,2.76 -2.24,5 -5,5 -2.76,0 -5,-2.24 -5,-5 0,-2.76 2.24,-5 5,-5 2.76,0 5,2.24 5,5 z"
         style="fill:#aa2224;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#aa2224;stroke-width:1.00000003pt;stroke-opacity:1"
         transform="matrix(0.4,0,0,0.4,2.96,0.4)"
         inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       id="b"
       orient="auto"
       overflow="visible"
       style="overflow:visible">
      <path
         stroke-width="NaN"
         d="m 0.98,0 c 0,0.552 -0.448,1 -1,1 -0.552,0 -1,-0.448 -1,-1 0,-0.552 0.448,-1 1,-1 0.552,0 1,0.448 1,1 z"
         id="path1541"
         inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
         style="fill:#8d8d8d;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#8d8d8d" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       id="c"
       orient="auto"
       overflow="visible"
       style="overflow:visible">
      <path
         stroke-width="NaN"
         d="m 0.98,0 c 0,0.552 -0.448,1 -1,1 -0.552,0 -1,-0.448 -1,-1 0,-0.552 0.448,-1 1,-1 0.552,0 1,0.448 1,1 z"
         id="path1544"
         inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
         style="fill:#8d8d8d;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#8d8d8d" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       id="d"
       orient="auto"
       overflow="visible"
       style="overflow:visible">
      <path
         stroke-width="NaN"
         d="m 0.98,0 c 0,0.552 -0.448,1 -1,1 -0.552,0 -1,-0.448 -1,-1 0,-0.552 0.448,-1 1,-1 0.552,0 1,0.448 1,1 z"
         id="path1547"
         inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
         style="fill:#d4ff2a;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#d4ff2a" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       id="e"
       orient="auto"
       overflow="visible"
       style="overflow:visible">
      <path
         stroke-width="NaN"
         d="m 0.98,0 c 0,0.552 -0.448,1 -1,1 -0.552,0 -1,-0.448 -1,-1 0,-0.552 0.448,-1 1,-1 0.552,0 1,0.448 1,1 z"
         id="path1550"
         inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
         style="fill:#d4ff2a;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#d4ff2a" />
    </marker>
  </defs>
  <path
     d="M 44.34832,22.48316 A 21.86515,21.86515 0 0 1 22.48316,44.34831 21.86515,21.86515 0 0 1 0.61799997,22.48316 21.86515,21.86515 0 0 1 22.48316,0.61799997 21.86515,21.86515 0 0 1 44.34832,22.48316 Z"
     id="path1555"
     style="opacity:1;fill:#d3b444;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#cfae3b;stroke-width:1.23599994;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1;paint-order:markers fill stroke"
     inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
  <path
     style="fill:none;stroke:#1b4d82;stroke-width:0.73026383;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-opacity:1;marker-end:url(#marker1763)"
     inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
     d="m 10.80167,33.15435 -0.27407,0.44526 c -0.10927,0.18848 -0.21307,0.38607 -0.24767,0.60187 -0.0483,0.30777 0.051,0.62009 0.17391,0.90691 0.12293,0.28683 0.27226,0.56637 0.33144,0.87322 0.0938,0.48442 -0.0601,1.00799 -0.39062,1.37403 -0.33053,0.36604 -0.82952,0.57092 -1.32304,0.55635 C 8.5781,37.89739 8.09733,37.66705 7.7668,37.30101 7.43627,36.93496 7.25598,36.43871 7.26235,35.94519 c 0.005,-0.43706 0.15389,-0.8714 0.41795,-1.22014"
     id="path1557" />
  <path
     style="fill:none;stroke:#1b4d82;stroke-width:0.73026383;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-opacity:1;marker-end:url(#marker1755)"
     inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
     d="m 33.65565,11.52324 0.27408,-0.44526 C 34.039,10.88949 34.1428,10.6919 34.1774,10.4761 34.2257,10.16834 34.1264,9.85602 34.00349,9.56919 33.88056,9.28237 33.73123,9.00283 33.67204,8.69597 33.57824,8.21156 33.73214,7.68799 34.06267,7.32195 34.3932,6.9559 34.89219,6.75103 35.38571,6.7656 c 0.49352,0.0146 0.97429,0.24494 1.30482,0.61098 0.33053,0.36604 0.51082,0.86229 0.50445,1.35581 -0.006,0.43707 -0.15389,0.8714 -0.41795,1.22014"
     id="path1559" />
  <path
     style="fill:#1b4d82;fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:0.89733565"
     inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
     d="m 37.33528,26.35893 c 0.509,-1.38859 -0.26042,-2.46669 -1.19191,-3.37178 -0.8277,-0.80493 -1.82202,-1.75646 -2.21447,-2.88191 -0.52084,-1.4924 0.16845,-3.02395 0.66106,-4.42985 0.24312,-0.69202 0.54542,-1.30118 0.43707,-2.05785 -0.26589,-1.84297 -2.70344,-3.04399 -4.25503,-1.95588 -0.48259,0.33873 -0.84044,0.8368 -1.23744,1.2675 -0.79219,0.85956 -1.72915,1.75919 -2.87098,2.07697 -1.77923,0.49534 -3.33901,-0.62373 -4.99349,-0.98613 -1.23198,-0.26952 -2.34103,0.17847 -2.99481,1.2766 -0.19122,0.32143 -0.35876,0.62282 -0.43889,0.99433 -0.39791,1.8466 1.34125,3.64677 3.16418,3.36632 1.15185,-0.17756 1.73552,-1.11725 2.4676,-1.92036 0.59551,-0.65287 1.33579,-1.21741 2.13617,-1.57344 3.43825,-1.53064 7.42739,1.527 7.01855,5.27393 -0.21124,1.93766 -2.04328,3.93724 -0.69475,5.78567 0.23037,0.31596 0.51355,0.49352 0.84135,0.68838 1.59985,0.94971 3.49927,0.2677 4.16761,-1.55432 z M 7.12216,18.31873 c -0.50901,1.3886 0.26041,2.4667 1.19191,3.37179 0.8277,0.80493 1.82202,1.75646 2.21447,2.8819 0.52084,1.4924 -0.16845,3.02396 -0.66106,4.42985 -0.24312,0.69203 -0.54542,1.30119 -0.43707,2.05786 0.26588,1.84296 2.70344,3.04398 4.25503,1.95587 0.48259,-0.33872 0.84044,-0.8368 1.23744,-1.26749 0.79218,-0.85957 1.72915,-1.75919 2.87098,-2.07698 1.77923,-0.49534 3.33901,0.62373 4.99348,0.98613 1.23199,0.26953 2.34104,-0.17847 2.99482,-1.27659 0.19122,-0.32143 0.35876,-0.62282 0.43889,-0.99433 0.39791,-1.84661 -1.34125,-3.64677 -3.16418,-3.36632 -1.15185,0.17756 -1.73552,1.11725 -2.46761,1.92036 -0.5955,0.65287 -1.33578,1.21741 -2.13616,1.57344 -3.43825,1.53064 -7.4274,-1.527 -7.01856,-5.27394 0.21125,-1.93766 2.04329,-3.93724 0.69476,-5.78566 C 11.89893,17.13865 11.61575,16.96109 11.28794,16.76624 9.6881,15.81653 7.78868,16.49853 7.12033,18.32055 Z"
     id="path1561" />
  <path
     style="fill:#a92121;fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:0.89733565"
     inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
     d="m 18.0643,37.46406 c 1.38859,0.509 2.46669,-0.26042 3.37178,-1.19191 0.80493,-0.8277 1.75646,-1.82202 2.88191,-2.21447 1.4924,-0.52084 3.02395,0.16845 4.42985,0.66106 0.69202,0.24312 1.30118,0.54542 2.05785,0.43707 1.84297,-0.26589 3.04399,-2.70344 1.95588,-4.25503 -0.33873,-0.48259 -0.83681,-0.84044 -1.2675,-1.23744 -0.85956,-0.79218 -1.75919,-1.72915 -2.07697,-2.87098 -0.49535,-1.77923 0.62373,-3.33901 0.98613,-4.99349 0.26952,-1.23198 -0.17847,-2.34103 -1.2766,-2.99481 -0.32143,-0.19122 -0.62282,-0.35876 -0.99433,-0.43889 -1.8466,-0.39791 -3.64677,1.34125 -3.36632,3.16418 0.17756,1.15185 1.11725,1.73552 1.92036,2.4676 0.65287,0.59551 1.21741,1.33579 1.57344,2.13617 1.53064,3.43825 -1.527,7.42739 -5.27393,7.01855 -1.93767,-0.21125 -3.93724,-2.04328 -5.78567,-0.69475 -0.31596,0.23037 -0.49352,0.51355 -0.68838,0.84135 -0.94971,1.59985 -0.2677,3.49927 1.55432,4.16761 z"
     id="path1563" />
  <path
     style="fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#aa2224;stroke-width:0.73000002;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1;marker-end:url(#DotS)"
     inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
     d="m 32.88442,33.7717 0.44526,0.27408 c 0.18848,0.10926 0.38607,0.21307 0.60187,0.24767 0.30777,0.0483 0.62009,-0.051 0.90691,-0.17392 0.28683,-0.12292 0.56637,-0.27225 0.87322,-0.33144 0.48442,-0.0938 1.00799,0.0601 1.37403,0.39063 0.36604,0.33053 0.57092,0.82951 0.55635,1.32303 -0.0146,0.49352 -0.24494,0.97429 -0.61098,1.30483 -0.36605,0.33053 -0.8623,0.51082 -1.35582,0.50444 -0.43706,-0.005 -0.8714,-0.15388 -1.22014,-0.41794"
     id="path1565" />
  <path
     style="fill:#aa2224;fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:0.89733565"
     inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
     d="m 26.6226,6.83936 c -1.38859,-0.509 -2.46669,0.26042 -3.37178,1.19192 -0.80493,0.8277 -1.75646,1.82202 -2.88191,2.21447 -1.4924,0.52084 -3.02395,-0.16845 -4.42985,-0.66106 -0.69202,-0.24312 -1.30118,-0.54542 -2.05785,-0.43707 -1.84297,0.26588 -3.04399,2.70344 -1.95588,4.25503 0.33873,0.48259 0.8368,0.84044 1.2675,1.23744 0.85956,0.79218 1.75919,1.72914 2.07697,2.87098 0.49534,1.77922 -0.62373,3.33901 -0.98613,4.99348 -0.26952,1.23198 0.17847,2.34104 1.2766,2.99482 0.32142,0.19122 0.62282,0.35876 0.99433,0.43889 1.8466,0.39791 3.64677,-1.34125 3.36632,-3.16418 -0.17756,-1.15185 -1.11725,-1.73552 -1.92036,-2.46761 -0.65287,-0.5955 -1.21742,-1.33578 -1.57344,-2.13616 -1.53065,-3.43825 1.527,-7.4274 5.27393,-7.01856 1.93766,0.21125 3.93724,2.04329 5.78567,0.69476 0.31596,-0.23037 0.49352,-0.51356 0.68838,-0.84136 0.94971,-1.59984 0.2677,-3.49926 -1.55432,-4.16761 z"
     id="path1567" />
  <path
     style="fill:none;stroke:#a92121;stroke-width:0.73026383;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-opacity:1;marker-end:url(#marker1759)"
     inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
     d="M 11.80237,10.53165 11.35711,10.25757 C 11.16863,10.1483 10.97104,10.0445 10.75524,10.0099 10.44747,9.9616 10.13515,10.0609 9.84833,10.18382 9.5615,10.30674 9.28196,10.45607 8.9751,10.51526 8.49069,10.60906 7.96712,10.45516 7.60108,10.12463 7.23504,9.7941 7.03016,9.29512 7.04473,8.8016 7.05933,8.30808 7.28967,7.8273 7.65571,7.49677 8.02176,7.16624 8.51801,6.98595 9.01153,6.99233 c 0.43706,0.005 0.8714,0.15388 1.22014,0.41794"
     id="path1569" />
  <animateTransform
     attributeName="transform"
     attributeType="XML"
     type="rotate"
     from="0"
     to="360"
     dur="5s"
     repeatCount="indefinite" />
</svg>
```

Here is the text + logo :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   id="svg8"
   version="1.1"
   viewBox="0 0 60.009521 7.646053"
   height="28.89847"
   width="226.80762"
   sodipodi:docname="LogoO2.svg"
   inkscape:version="0.92.4 (5da689c313, 2019-01-14)">
  <sodipodi:namedview
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1"
     objecttolerance="10"
     gridtolerance="10"
     guidetolerance="10"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:window-width="1366"
     inkscape:window-height="705"
     id="namedview974"
     showgrid="false"
     fit-margin-top="0"
     fit-margin-left="0"
     fit-margin-right="0"
     fit-margin-bottom="0"
     inkscape:zoom="1.5181291"
     inkscape:cx="64.199039"
     inkscape:cy="-10.196825"
     inkscape:window-x="-8"
     inkscape:window-y="-8"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1"
     inkscape:current-layer="svg8"
     units="px" />
  <defs
     id="defs2">
    <marker
       inkscape:isstock="true"
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="marker1763"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="DotS">
      <path
         inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
         transform="matrix(0.2,0,0,0.2,1.48,0.2)"
         style="fill:#1b4d82;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#1b4d82;stroke-width:1.00000003pt;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="m -2.5,-1 c 0,2.76 -2.24,5 -5,5 -2.76,0 -5,-2.24 -5,-5 0,-2.76 2.24,-5 5,-5 2.76,0 5,2.24 5,5 z"
         id="path1761" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       inkscape:isstock="true"
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="marker1755"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="DotS">
      <path
         inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
         transform="matrix(0.2,0,0,0.2,1.48,0.2)"
         style="fill:#1b4d82;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#1b4d82;stroke-width:1.00000003pt;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="m -2.5,-1 c 0,2.76 -2.24,5 -5,5 -2.76,0 -5,-2.24 -5,-5 0,-2.76 2.24,-5 5,-5 2.76,0 5,2.24 5,5 z"
         id="path1753" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       inkscape:isstock="true"
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="DotS"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="DotS">
      <path
         inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
         transform="matrix(0.2,0,0,0.2,1.48,0.2)"
         style="fill:#aa2224;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#aa2224;stroke-width:1.00000003pt;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="m -2.5,-1 c 0,2.76 -2.24,5 -5,5 -2.76,0 -5,-2.24 -5,-5 0,-2.76 2.24,-5 5,-5 2.76,0 5,2.24 5,5 z"
         id="path1553" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       inkscape:isstock="true"
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="marker1759"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="DotS">
      <path
         inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
         transform="matrix(0.2,0,0,0.2,1.48,0.2)"
         style="fill:#a92121;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#a92121;stroke-width:1.00000003pt;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="m -2.5,-1 c 0,2.76 -2.24,5 -5,5 -2.76,0 -5,-2.24 -5,-5 0,-2.76 2.24,-5 5,-5 2.76,0 5,2.24 5,5 z"
         id="path1757" />
    </marker>
  </defs>
  <metadata
     id="metadata5">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     transform="matrix(0.56629515,0,0,0.56629515,-27.797677,-51.624623)"
     id="layer1">
    <text
       id="text817"
       y="101.96429"
       x="49.136906"
       style="font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:10.58333302px;line-height:1.25;font-family:sans-serif;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.1;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:0;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:1;stroke-opacity:1"
       xml:space="preserve"><tspan
         style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:12.69999981px;line-height:0px;font-family:'Tropical Summer Signature';-inkscape-font-specification:'Tropical Summer Signature';stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.1;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:0;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:1;stroke-opacity:1"
         y="101.96429"
         x="49.136906"
         id="tspan815">My Smart Closet</tspan></text>
  </g>
  <g
     id="g871"
     transform="matrix(0.17003611,0,0,0.17003961,52.363618,0)">
    <path
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
       style="opacity:1;fill:#d3b444;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#cfae3b;stroke-width:1.23599994;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1;paint-order:markers fill stroke"
       id="path1555"
       d="M 44.34832,22.48316 A 21.86515,21.86515 0 0 1 22.48316,44.34831 21.86515,21.86515 0 0 1 0.61799997,22.48316 21.86515,21.86515 0 0 1 22.48316,0.61799997 21.86515,21.86515 0 0 1 44.34832,22.48316 Z" />
    <path
       id="path1557"
       d="m 10.80167,33.15435 -0.27407,0.44526 c -0.10927,0.18848 -0.21307,0.38607 -0.24767,0.60187 -0.0483,0.30777 0.051,0.62009 0.17391,0.90691 0.12293,0.28683 0.27226,0.56637 0.33144,0.87322 0.0938,0.48442 -0.0601,1.00799 -0.39062,1.37403 -0.33053,0.36604 -0.82952,0.57092 -1.32304,0.55635 C 8.5781,37.89739 8.09733,37.66705 7.7668,37.30101 7.43627,36.93496 7.25598,36.43871 7.26235,35.94519 c 0.005,-0.43706 0.15389,-0.8714 0.41795,-1.22014"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
       style="fill:none;stroke:#1b4d82;stroke-width:0.73026383;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-opacity:1;marker-end:url(#marker1763)" />
    <path
       id="path1559"
       d="m 33.65565,11.52324 0.27408,-0.44526 C 34.039,10.88949 34.1428,10.6919 34.1774,10.4761 34.2257,10.16834 34.1264,9.85602 34.00349,9.56919 33.88056,9.28237 33.73123,9.00283 33.67204,8.69597 33.57824,8.21156 33.73214,7.68799 34.06267,7.32195 34.3932,6.9559 34.89219,6.75103 35.38571,6.7656 c 0.49352,0.0146 0.97429,0.24494 1.30482,0.61098 0.33053,0.36604 0.51082,0.86229 0.50445,1.35581 -0.006,0.43707 -0.15389,0.8714 -0.41795,1.22014"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
       style="fill:none;stroke:#1b4d82;stroke-width:0.73026383;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-opacity:1;marker-end:url(#marker1755)" />
    <path
       id="path1561"
       d="m 37.33528,26.35893 c 0.509,-1.38859 -0.26042,-2.46669 -1.19191,-3.37178 -0.8277,-0.80493 -1.82202,-1.75646 -2.21447,-2.88191 -0.52084,-1.4924 0.16845,-3.02395 0.66106,-4.42985 0.24312,-0.69202 0.54542,-1.30118 0.43707,-2.05785 -0.26589,-1.84297 -2.70344,-3.04399 -4.25503,-1.95588 -0.48259,0.33873 -0.84044,0.8368 -1.23744,1.2675 -0.79219,0.85956 -1.72915,1.75919 -2.87098,2.07697 -1.77923,0.49534 -3.33901,-0.62373 -4.99349,-0.98613 -1.23198,-0.26952 -2.34103,0.17847 -2.99481,1.2766 -0.19122,0.32143 -0.35876,0.62282 -0.43889,0.99433 -0.39791,1.8466 1.34125,3.64677 3.16418,3.36632 1.15185,-0.17756 1.73552,-1.11725 2.4676,-1.92036 0.59551,-0.65287 1.33579,-1.21741 2.13617,-1.57344 3.43825,-1.53064 7.42739,1.527 7.01855,5.27393 -0.21124,1.93766 -2.04328,3.93724 -0.69475,5.78567 0.23037,0.31596 0.51355,0.49352 0.84135,0.68838 1.59985,0.94971 3.49927,0.2677 4.16761,-1.55432 z M 7.12216,18.31873 c -0.50901,1.3886 0.26041,2.4667 1.19191,3.37179 0.8277,0.80493 1.82202,1.75646 2.21447,2.8819 0.52084,1.4924 -0.16845,3.02396 -0.66106,4.42985 -0.24312,0.69203 -0.54542,1.30119 -0.43707,2.05786 0.26588,1.84296 2.70344,3.04398 4.25503,1.95587 0.48259,-0.33872 0.84044,-0.8368 1.23744,-1.26749 0.79218,-0.85957 1.72915,-1.75919 2.87098,-2.07698 1.77923,-0.49534 3.33901,0.62373 4.99348,0.98613 1.23199,0.26953 2.34104,-0.17847 2.99482,-1.27659 0.19122,-0.32143 0.35876,-0.62282 0.43889,-0.99433 0.39791,-1.84661 -1.34125,-3.64677 -3.16418,-3.36632 -1.15185,0.17756 -1.73552,1.11725 -2.46761,1.92036 -0.5955,0.65287 -1.33578,1.21741 -2.13616,1.57344 -3.43825,1.53064 -7.4274,-1.527 -7.01856,-5.27394 0.21125,-1.93766 2.04329,-3.93724 0.69476,-5.78566 C 11.89893,17.13865 11.61575,16.96109 11.28794,16.76624 9.6881,15.81653 7.78868,16.49853 7.12033,18.32055 Z"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
       style="fill:#1b4d82;fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:0.89733565" />
    <path
       id="path1563"
       d="m 18.0643,37.46406 c 1.38859,0.509 2.46669,-0.26042 3.37178,-1.19191 0.80493,-0.8277 1.75646,-1.82202 2.88191,-2.21447 1.4924,-0.52084 3.02395,0.16845 4.42985,0.66106 0.69202,0.24312 1.30118,0.54542 2.05785,0.43707 1.84297,-0.26589 3.04399,-2.70344 1.95588,-4.25503 -0.33873,-0.48259 -0.83681,-0.84044 -1.2675,-1.23744 -0.85956,-0.79218 -1.75919,-1.72915 -2.07697,-2.87098 -0.49535,-1.77923 0.62373,-3.33901 0.98613,-4.99349 0.26952,-1.23198 -0.17847,-2.34103 -1.2766,-2.99481 -0.32143,-0.19122 -0.62282,-0.35876 -0.99433,-0.43889 -1.8466,-0.39791 -3.64677,1.34125 -3.36632,3.16418 0.17756,1.15185 1.11725,1.73552 1.92036,2.4676 0.65287,0.59551 1.21741,1.33579 1.57344,2.13617 1.53064,3.43825 -1.527,7.42739 -5.27393,7.01855 -1.93767,-0.21125 -3.93724,-2.04328 -5.78567,-0.69475 -0.31596,0.23037 -0.49352,0.51355 -0.68838,0.84135 -0.94971,1.59985 -0.2677,3.49927 1.55432,4.16761 z"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
       style="fill:#a92121;fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:0.89733565" />
    <path
       id="path1565"
       d="m 32.88442,33.7717 0.44526,0.27408 c 0.18848,0.10926 0.38607,0.21307 0.60187,0.24767 0.30777,0.0483 0.62009,-0.051 0.90691,-0.17392 0.28683,-0.12292 0.56637,-0.27225 0.87322,-0.33144 0.48442,-0.0938 1.00799,0.0601 1.37403,0.39063 0.36604,0.33053 0.57092,0.82951 0.55635,1.32303 -0.0146,0.49352 -0.24494,0.97429 -0.61098,1.30483 -0.36605,0.33053 -0.8623,0.51082 -1.35582,0.50444 -0.43706,-0.005 -0.8714,-0.15388 -1.22014,-0.41794"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
       style="fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#aa2224;stroke-width:0.73000002;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1;marker-end:url(#DotS)" />
    <path
       id="path1567"
       d="m 26.6226,6.83936 c -1.38859,-0.509 -2.46669,0.26042 -3.37178,1.19192 -0.80493,0.8277 -1.75646,1.82202 -2.88191,2.21447 -1.4924,0.52084 -3.02395,-0.16845 -4.42985,-0.66106 -0.69202,-0.24312 -1.30118,-0.54542 -2.05785,-0.43707 -1.84297,0.26588 -3.04399,2.70344 -1.95588,4.25503 0.33873,0.48259 0.8368,0.84044 1.2675,1.23744 0.85956,0.79218 1.75919,1.72914 2.07697,2.87098 0.49534,1.77922 -0.62373,3.33901 -0.98613,4.99348 -0.26952,1.23198 0.17847,2.34104 1.2766,2.99482 0.32142,0.19122 0.62282,0.35876 0.99433,0.43889 1.8466,0.39791 3.64677,-1.34125 3.36632,-3.16418 -0.17756,-1.15185 -1.11725,-1.73552 -1.92036,-2.46761 -0.65287,-0.5955 -1.21742,-1.33578 -1.57344,-2.13616 -1.53065,-3.43825 1.527,-7.4274 5.27393,-7.01856 1.93766,0.21125 3.93724,2.04329 5.78567,0.69476 0.31596,-0.23037 0.49352,-0.51356 0.68838,-0.84136 0.94971,-1.59984 0.2677,-3.49926 -1.55432,-4.16761 z"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
       style="fill:#aa2224;fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:0.89733565" />
    <path
       id="path1569"
       d="M 11.80237,10.53165 11.35711,10.25757 C 11.16863,10.1483 10.97104,10.0445 10.75524,10.0099 10.44747,9.9616 10.13515,10.0609 9.84833,10.18382 9.5615,10.30674 9.28196,10.45607 8.9751,10.51526 8.49069,10.60906 7.96712,10.45516 7.60108,10.12463 7.23504,9.7941 7.03016,9.29512 7.04473,8.8016 7.05933,8.30808 7.28967,7.8273 7.65571,7.49677 8.02176,7.16624 8.51801,6.98595 9.01153,6.99233 c 0.43706,0.005 0.8714,0.15388 1.22014,0.41794"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
       style="fill:none;stroke:#a92121;stroke-width:0.73026383;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-opacity:1;marker-end:url(#marker1759)" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Please any one can tell me where to add the `animateTransform` function to make the logo rotate in the same place (right) on its center without rotating the text.

Comment: Your second example doesn't have an animateTransform at all so it's a bit hard to see what you're doing wrong. Ensure the animate transform is in the path's <g> tag.

Comment: Please check my answer Mr Robert.

Comment: The circle changes its position, and even if I add  : from="0 14 113"
     to="360 14 113"

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   id="svg8"
   version="1.1"
   viewBox="0 0 60.009521 7.646053"
   height="28.89847"
   width="226.80762"
   sodipodi:docname="LogoO2.svg"
   inkscape:version="0.92.4 (5da689c313, 2019-01-14)">
  <sodipodi:namedview
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1"
     objecttolerance="10"
     gridtolerance="10"
     guidetolerance="10"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:window-width="1366"
     inkscape:window-height="705"
     id="namedview974"
     showgrid="false"
     fit-margin-top="0"
     fit-margin-left="0"
     fit-margin-right="0"
     fit-margin-bottom="0"
     inkscape:zoom="1.5181291"
     inkscape:cx="64.199039"
     inkscape:cy="-10.196825"
     inkscape:window-x="-8"
     inkscape:window-y="-8"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1"
     inkscape:current-layer="svg8"
     units="px" />
  <defs
     id="defs2">
    <marker
       inkscape:isstock="true"
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="marker1763"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="DotS">
      <path
         inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
         transform="matrix(0.2,0,0,0.2,1.48,0.2)"
         style="fill:#1b4d82;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#1b4d82;stroke-width:1.00000003pt;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="m -2.5,-1 c 0,2.76 -2.24,5 -5,5 -2.76,0 -5,-2.24 -5,-5 0,-2.76 2.24,-5 5,-5 2.76,0 5,2.24 5,5 z"
         id="path1761" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       inkscape:isstock="true"
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="marker1755"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="DotS">
      <path
         inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
         transform="matrix(0.2,0,0,0.2,1.48,0.2)"
         style="fill:#1b4d82;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#1b4d82;stroke-width:1.00000003pt;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="m -2.5,-1 c 0,2.76 -2.24,5 -5,5 -2.76,0 -5,-2.24 -5,-5 0,-2.76 2.24,-5 5,-5 2.76,0 5,2.24 5,5 z"
         id="path1753" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       inkscape:isstock="true"
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="DotS"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="DotS">
      <path
         inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
         transform="matrix(0.2,0,0,0.2,1.48,0.2)"
         style="fill:#aa2224;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#aa2224;stroke-width:1.00000003pt;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="m -2.5,-1 c 0,2.76 -2.24,5 -5,5 -2.76,0 -5,-2.24 -5,-5 0,-2.76 2.24,-5 5,-5 2.76,0 5,2.24 5,5 z"
         id="path1553" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       inkscape:isstock="true"
       style="overflow:visible"
       id="marker1759"
       refX="0"
       refY="0"
       orient="auto"
       inkscape:stockid="DotS">
      <path
         inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
         transform="matrix(0.2,0,0,0.2,1.48,0.2)"
         style="fill:#a92121;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#a92121;stroke-width:1.00000003pt;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="m -2.5,-1 c 0,2.76 -2.24,5 -5,5 -2.76,0 -5,-2.24 -5,-5 0,-2.76 2.24,-5 5,-5 2.76,0 5,2.24 5,5 z"
         id="path1757" />
    </marker>
  </defs>
  <metadata
     id="metadata5">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     transform="matrix(0.56629515,0,0,0.56629515,-27.797677,-51.624623)"
     id="layer1">
    <text
       id="text817"
       y="101.96429"
       x="49.136906"
       style="font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:10.58333302px;line-height:1.25;font-family:sans-serif;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.1;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:0;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:1;stroke-opacity:1"
       xml:space="preserve"><tspan
         style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:12.69999981px;line-height:0px;font-family:'Tropical Summer Signature';-inkscape-font-specification:'Tropical Summer Signature';stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.1;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:0;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:1;stroke-opacity:1"
         y="101.96429"
         x="49.136906"
         id="tspan815">My Smart Closet</tspan></text>
  </g>
  <g
     id="g871"
     transform="matrix(0.17003611,0,0,0.17003961,52.363618,0)">
    <path
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
       style="opacity:1;fill:#d3b444;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#cfae3b;stroke-width:1.23599994;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1;paint-order:markers fill stroke"
       id="path1555"
       d="M 44.34832,22.48316 A 21.86515,21.86515 0 0 1 22.48316,44.34831 21.86515,21.86515 0 0 1 0.61799997,22.48316 21.86515,21.86515 0 0 1 22.48316,0.61799997 21.86515,21.86515 0 0 1 44.34832,22.48316 Z" />
    <path
       id="path1557"
       d="m 10.80167,33.15435 -0.27407,0.44526 c -0.10927,0.18848 -0.21307,0.38607 -0.24767,0.60187 -0.0483,0.30777 0.051,0.62009 0.17391,0.90691 0.12293,0.28683 0.27226,0.56637 0.33144,0.87322 0.0938,0.48442 -0.0601,1.00799 -0.39062,1.37403 -0.33053,0.36604 -0.82952,0.57092 -1.32304,0.55635 C 8.5781,37.89739 8.09733,37.66705 7.7668,37.30101 7.43627,36.93496 7.25598,36.43871 7.26235,35.94519 c 0.005,-0.43706 0.15389,-0.8714 0.41795,-1.22014"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
       style="fill:none;stroke:#1b4d82;stroke-width:0.73026383;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-opacity:1;marker-end:url(#marker1763)" />
    <path
       id="path1559"
       d="m 33.65565,11.52324 0.27408,-0.44526 C 34.039,10.88949 34.1428,10.6919 34.1774,10.4761 34.2257,10.16834 34.1264,9.85602 34.00349,9.56919 33.88056,9.28237 33.73123,9.00283 33.67204,8.69597 33.57824,8.21156 33.73214,7.68799 34.06267,7.32195 34.3932,6.9559 34.89219,6.75103 35.38571,6.7656 c 0.49352,0.0146 0.97429,0.24494 1.30482,0.61098 0.33053,0.36604 0.51082,0.86229 0.50445,1.35581 -0.006,0.43707 -0.15389,0.8714 -0.41795,1.22014"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
       style="fill:none;stroke:#1b4d82;stroke-width:0.73026383;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-opacity:1;marker-end:url(#marker1755)" />
    <path
       id="path1561"
       d="m 37.33528,26.35893 c 0.509,-1.38859 -0.26042,-2.46669 -1.19191,-3.37178 -0.8277,-0.80493 -1.82202,-1.75646 -2.21447,-2.88191 -0.52084,-1.4924 0.16845,-3.02395 0.66106,-4.42985 0.24312,-0.69202 0.54542,-1.30118 0.43707,-2.05785 -0.26589,-1.84297 -2.70344,-3.04399 -4.25503,-1.95588 -0.48259,0.33873 -0.84044,0.8368 -1.23744,1.2675 -0.79219,0.85956 -1.72915,1.75919 -2.87098,2.07697 -1.77923,0.49534 -3.33901,-0.62373 -4.99349,-0.98613 -1.23198,-0.26952 -2.34103,0.17847 -2.99481,1.2766 -0.19122,0.32143 -0.35876,0.62282 -0.43889,0.99433 -0.39791,1.8466 1.34125,3.64677 3.16418,3.36632 1.15185,-0.17756 1.73552,-1.11725 2.4676,-1.92036 0.59551,-0.65287 1.33579,-1.21741 2.13617,-1.57344 3.43825,-1.53064 7.42739,1.527 7.01855,5.27393 -0.21124,1.93766 -2.04328,3.93724 -0.69475,5.78567 0.23037,0.31596 0.51355,0.49352 0.84135,0.68838 1.59985,0.94971 3.49927,0.2677 4.16761,-1.55432 z M 7.12216,18.31873 c -0.50901,1.3886 0.26041,2.4667 1.19191,3.37179 0.8277,0.80493 1.82202,1.75646 2.21447,2.8819 0.52084,1.4924 -0.16845,3.02396 -0.66106,4.42985 -0.24312,0.69203 -0.54542,1.30119 -0.43707,2.05786 0.26588,1.84296 2.70344,3.04398 4.25503,1.95587 0.48259,-0.33872 0.84044,-0.8368 1.23744,-1.26749 0.79218,-0.85957 1.72915,-1.75919 2.87098,-2.07698 1.77923,-0.49534 3.33901,0.62373 4.99348,0.98613 1.23199,0.26953 2.34104,-0.17847 2.99482,-1.27659 0.19122,-0.32143 0.35876,-0.62282 0.43889,-0.99433 0.39791,-1.84661 -1.34125,-3.64677 -3.16418,-3.36632 -1.15185,0.17756 -1.73552,1.11725 -2.46761,1.92036 -0.5955,0.65287 -1.33578,1.21741 -2.13616,1.57344 -3.43825,1.53064 -7.4274,-1.527 -7.01856,-5.27394 0.21125,-1.93766 2.04329,-3.93724 0.69476,-5.78566 C 11.89893,17.13865 11.61575,16.96109 11.28794,16.76624 9.6881,15.81653 7.78868,16.49853 7.12033,18.32055 Z"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
       style="fill:#1b4d82;fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:0.89733565" />
    <path
       id="path1563"
       d="m 18.0643,37.46406 c 1.38859,0.509 2.46669,-0.26042 3.37178,-1.19191 0.80493,-0.8277 1.75646,-1.82202 2.88191,-2.21447 1.4924,-0.52084 3.02395,0.16845 4.42985,0.66106 0.69202,0.24312 1.30118,0.54542 2.05785,0.43707 1.84297,-0.26589 3.04399,-2.70344 1.95588,-4.25503 -0.33873,-0.48259 -0.83681,-0.84044 -1.2675,-1.23744 -0.85956,-0.79218 -1.75919,-1.72915 -2.07697,-2.87098 -0.49535,-1.77923 0.62373,-3.33901 0.98613,-4.99349 0.26952,-1.23198 -0.17847,-2.34103 -1.2766,-2.99481 -0.32143,-0.19122 -0.62282,-0.35876 -0.99433,-0.43889 -1.8466,-0.39791 -3.64677,1.34125 -3.36632,3.16418 0.17756,1.15185 1.11725,1.73552 1.92036,2.4676 0.65287,0.59551 1.21741,1.33579 1.57344,2.13617 1.53064,3.43825 -1.527,7.42739 -5.27393,7.01855 -1.93767,-0.21125 -3.93724,-2.04328 -5.78567,-0.69475 -0.31596,0.23037 -0.49352,0.51355 -0.68838,0.84135 -0.94971,1.59985 -0.2677,3.49927 1.55432,4.16761 z"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
       style="fill:#a92121;fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:0.89733565" />
    <path
       id="path1565"
       d="m 32.88442,33.7717 0.44526,0.27408 c 0.18848,0.10926 0.38607,0.21307 0.60187,0.24767 0.30777,0.0483 0.62009,-0.051 0.90691,-0.17392 0.28683,-0.12292 0.56637,-0.27225 0.87322,-0.33144 0.48442,-0.0938 1.00799,0.0601 1.37403,0.39063 0.36604,0.33053 0.57092,0.82951 0.55635,1.32303 -0.0146,0.49352 -0.24494,0.97429 -0.61098,1.30483 -0.36605,0.33053 -0.8623,0.51082 -1.35582,0.50444 -0.43706,-0.005 -0.8714,-0.15388 -1.22014,-0.41794"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
       style="fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#aa2224;stroke-width:0.73000002;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1;marker-end:url(#DotS)" />
    <path
       id="path1567"
       d="m 26.6226,6.83936 c -1.38859,-0.509 -2.46669,0.26042 -3.37178,1.19192 -0.80493,0.8277 -1.75646,1.82202 -2.88191,2.21447 -1.4924,0.52084 -3.02395,-0.16845 -4.42985,-0.66106 -0.69202,-0.24312 -1.30118,-0.54542 -2.05785,-0.43707 -1.84297,0.26588 -3.04399,2.70344 -1.95588,4.25503 0.33873,0.48259 0.8368,0.84044 1.2675,1.23744 0.85956,0.79218 1.75919,1.72914 2.07697,2.87098 0.49534,1.77922 -0.62373,3.33901 -0.98613,4.99348 -0.26952,1.23198 0.17847,2.34104 1.2766,2.99482 0.32142,0.19122 0.62282,0.35876 0.99433,0.43889 1.8466,0.39791 3.64677,-1.34125 3.36632,-3.16418 -0.17756,-1.15185 -1.11725,-1.73552 -1.92036,-2.46761 -0.65287,-0.5955 -1.21742,-1.33578 -1.57344,-2.13616 -1.53065,-3.43825 1.527,-7.4274 5.27393,-7.01856 1.93766,0.21125 3.93724,2.04329 5.78567,0.69476 0.31596,-0.23037 0.49352,-0.51356 0.68838,-0.84136 0.94971,-1.59984 0.2677,-3.49926 -1.55432,-4.16761 z"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
       style="fill:#aa2224;fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:0.89733565" />
    <path
       id="path1569"
       d="M 11.80237,10.53165 11.35711,10.25757 C 11.16863,10.1483 10.97104,10.0445 10.75524,10.0099 10.44747,9.9616 10.13515,10.0609 9.84833,10.18382 9.5615,10.30674 9.28196,10.45607 8.9751,10.51526 8.49069,10.60906 7.96712,10.45516 7.60108,10.12463 7.23504,9.7941 7.03016,9.29512 7.04473,8.8016 7.05933,8.30808 7.28967,7.8273 7.65571,7.49677 8.02176,7.16624 8.51801,6.98595 9.01153,6.99233 c 0.43706,0.005 0.8714,0.15388 1.22014,0.41794"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
       style="fill:none;stroke:#a92121;stroke-width:0.73026383;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-opacity:1;marker-end:url(#marker1759)" />
       <animateTransform
     attributeName="transform"
     attributeType="XML"
     type="rotate"
     from="0"
     to="360"
     dur="5s"
     repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </g>
</svg>
```